# After receiving the signal how to render it out into template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm having a hard time rending out into template after receiving the signal.

How do I render the "hehe" into the page or html file i want?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("hehes")
```

Comment: Signals are not meant to return things to be rendered in a view. Can you give a little more context as to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know sorry, now I know thanks. :) I just wanted to create a notification on my system, example if you post something then it will notif other user that you post something at your wall.

Comment: You should do that in your view that handles creating the post

Comment: Ohh thanks man! :) Ahmmm and also I'm new here in Django do you got some tips or references on how to learn Django quickly? I'm from php -> python

Comment: No worries. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/) is a really good reference for almost everything you'd like to do. [Classy Class-Based Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/) is great for learning all of the things that you can do with class based views. Some of the best places to learn are other peoples projects too